# iPhone app crash report from Google analytics - crash text too long

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, selector, forwarding

Two weeks ago the iPhone app I have developed was made available at App Store. The app presents a list of weather stations, implements a map, has some charts and some buttons for sorting the stations according to distance from the device's position.

Through Google analytics I see that is has crashed more than 50 times with the same reported exception description. The problem is that the description cuts mid sentence and leaves me clueless. The app has not crashed during recent testing on my devices. There are no crash reports reported in iTunes Connect.

I would appreciate any tips which might point me in the right debug-direction.

The sentence:

```
    NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ___forwarding___ _CF_forwarding_prep_0 _mh_execute_header -[UIViewController v
```

Comment: I still haven't figured this one out. Itunes connect does not show any crash reports and the app which now has passed 1000 downloads have reached 100 crashes according to google analytics. I have yet to experience a crash myself... I am grateful for any suggestions on how to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to most likely be related to the Shinobi charts used in the app. The app polls a webservice with weather data. Sometimes the data can be invalid and this was not handled correctly in the app. When invalid data was present the chart was not able to render in a new UIViewController and crashed the app.

This bug was somewhat hard to find, particularly because of the strange, amputated crash report in google analytics.

Another possible explanation for the crash could be that it was possible for IOS5 users to install the app. The app would then not start because "Autolayout" which needs at least iOS6 was used...

iTunes Connect still does not contain a crash report. The app has about 200 users.